# How do you register a FIDE rating?

Tags: rating, fide

I want to register a FIDE rating, but I can find nothing about that on the official website. How do I register an official FIDE rating?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> how do I register an official FIDE rating?

You don't register a FIDE rating because you have no authority to assign yourself a FIDE rating. Only FIDE can do that.

What you need to do is play in one or more FIDE rated tournaments where you:

1. Play at least 5 games against players who already have a FIDE rating
2. Score at least half a point against them
3. Get a rating of at least 1000

In that case in the month after the tournament organisers submit the results of their tournaments to FIDE for rating then you will get a FIDE rating. Actually the regulations say that the results must be submitted at least 3 days before the end of the month but my experience is that FIDE are more efficient than that and often results submitted two days before still get in to the next list.

The latest FIDE rating regulations are [here](https://www.fide.com/docs/regulations/FIDE%20Rating%20Regulations%202022.pdf).

Comment: Interesting, only needing 5 games for an initial rating must be relatively new? I recall needing 9 or maybe even 11 games some years back.